# Tomcat 7 slow startup time with Jersey deployed

Tags: jersey, tomcat7

Using Tomcat 7, Jeresy 1.12.

Time for launch Tomcat without Jersey is 4 seconds.

When I add the jars of Jersey to tomcat/lib directory, the time for launch goes for 50 seconds. It doesn't matter which servlets I use - even if web.xml is empty (no servlets) it takes that time.

The jar that cause the problem is jersey-servlet-1.12. When I remove it from lib directory, launch time goes normal again. I suspect that the services defined in that jar (\META-INF\services\*) cause the trouble but couldn't find the exact cause...

BTW: metadata-complete="true" didn't solve the problem.

**Edit:** Problem was confirmed by Jersey team ([issue JERSEY-1317](http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-1317)). A workaround to this problem is to remove `META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer` file from `jersey-servlet.jar`. This will disable some of Servlet3 functionality.

Comment: Wow! Can you please file an issue and describe what you are doing? http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY

Comment: @Martin, please review [link](http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-1317)

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the jar to **tomcat.util.scan.DefaultJarScanner.jarsToSkip** list at **catalina.properties**

This way you can take a newer version of the jar and you don't need to keep in mind that you should edit it.

See http://tomcat.10.x6.nabble.com/tomcat-7-0-29-startup-time-td4984446.html